# Powershell – Ping Server Process with SQL data

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I have a process that gets a list of servers from a SQL database table.  From there, that list goes through a loop and does a ping test.  The server and the ping test result are sent back to the same SQL database table but updates the column ‘IS_PINGABLE’ with the result.

The following Powershell script does this, but is super slow.  I took part of the code from here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-Script-to-ping-15e0610a and added some other steps.

If anyone has any suggestion to make this faster, better, strong, please let me know below.  Many thanks in advance.

```
$MasterServerConnString = dbserver,1433


#**********************************************************************
#region Get Server List
#Get Server list from SQL DB Table and save to temp Powershell table
#**********************************************************************

$ping_cmd = "Set NOCOUNT ON; SELECT distinct machinename, IS_PINGABLE FROM [DB].[dbo].[TABLE] order by 1"

$ping_cn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=$MasterServerConnString;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DB");
$ping_cn.Open()
            $ping_a = $ping_cn.CreateCommand()
            $ping_a.CommandText = $ping_cmd
            $ping_a = $ping_a.ExecuteReader()
            $ping = new-object “System.Data.DataTable” "computername"
            $ping.Load($ping_a)
$ping_cn.Close()

$Server = $ping.Item(0)

#**********************************************************************
#endregion

#**********************************************************************
#region Ping Sever Test
#Ping each server to see if there is connectivity.  If pingable, 1.  If not pingable 0.
#**********************************************************************

$PCData = foreach ($PC in $Server) {

    Write-Verbose "Checking computer'$PC'"
    try {
        Test-Connection -ComputerName $PC -Count 2 -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null

        $Props = @{
            ComputerName   = $PC
            Status         = 1

        }
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Props
    } catch { # either ping failed or access denied 
        try {
            Test-Connection -ComputerName $PC -Count 2 -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
            $Props = @{
                ComputerName   = $PC
                Status         = 0

            }
            New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Props            
        } catch {
            $Props = @{
                ComputerName   = $PC
                Status         = 0

            }
            New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Props              
        }
    }
}

#**********************************************************************
#endregion


#**********************************************************************
#region Upload Results
#Upload the ping results for each server back to the database table
#**********************************************************************

foreach ($sv in $PCData)
{

$svr_name = $sv.ComputerName
$svr_stat = $sv.Status


$Updatequery = " 
Update [DB].[dbo].[TABLE]
SET
IS_PINGABLE = $svr_stat
WHERE
MachineName = '$svr_name'
"

$A_cn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=$MasterServerConnString;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DB");
$A_cn.Open() 
        $command = $A_cn.CreateCommand()
        $command.CommandText = $Updatequery
        $result = $command.ExecuteReader()
$A_cn.Close()

}
#**********************************************************************
#endregion
```

Comment: Try to only execute a single query at the end of the process. Even if you just open one connection and pass a ton of queries through, it still goes faster. Opening and closing connections has a lot of overhead.

Comment: This may be a little drastic. But, you can ping multiple servers at once, [Using this Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Multithreaded-PowerShell-0bc3f59b). This would most defiantly speed up the `test-connection` for multiple servers